# How to bypass Windows 10 PIN complexity requirement

Tags: windows-10, pin

I have recently updated Windows 10 on a PC. When I try to enter the same old PIN that I have been using, it says my PIN does not pass the complexity requirement.

I know the reason it cannot pass because the PIN is too simple. However, this is a shared PC for presentation purpose and I am sharing the same PIN across multiple PCs. I really want to keep the same PIN so I don't have to update everyone and every other PCs. PIN is still useful to lock the screen during break.

I searched and found registry that can change the various requirements of PIN.

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-pin-complexity-windows-10

But I cannot find a way to turn off PIN complexity check. Does anyone know of a way?

Comment: "But I cannot find a way to turn off PIN complexity check." - If you set those polices to **disabled** then the complexity check is disabled.

Comment: You already linked to the article how to change it. If you’re looking for a “pin complexity” option there isn’t one. But you can simply change the length requirements, the character requirements, number requirements, special character requirements, etc.

Comment: The issue is the last requirement "Can't be a number pattern". While my PIN is not 1234, it is picked up as a pattern. I tried all the visible registry options and none worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't actually mind not using a PIN, you can set the password complexity to a minimum setting and put the pin in there.

To do this, Open `gpedit.msc` and browse to the following section: `Computer Configuration` > `Windows Settings` > `Security Settings` > `Account Policies` > `Password Policies`. Here you can disable `Password must meet complexity requirements` after which you can have a password with just a space if you wanted to.

Of course, you can also set a blank password, which means no password at all.

Do note, these settigs will be greyed out if your computer is part of a domain. In that case, the domain controller will need to set the password requirements, but I doubt the pc's in question are part of a domain.

Changing settings regarding to PIN should also be possible based on policies, but with the limited time I currently have, I know of this setting, but couldn't find one for PIN related settings.